# Android Kotlin Volley String Request stopped working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I'm trying to get simple GET request from my server in Android app. At first it worked, but after I tried to parse it and added some changes it stopped working, idk why. Here's my code before and after, I even rolled back all the refactor changes but it still didn't work. I just don't get any response, not even error. I checked even on Debug and tried to print it, didn't help. First time it worked with my ip+port, I didn't even needed to use port-forwarding, and this time I checked on my phone browser, it still works, I can get the answer in browser, but Kotlin code doen't work for some reason. Here's the first version (was working):

```
package com.example.tvseriesprojectapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val layout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.root)

        val textView = TextView(this)
        textView.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "http://192.168.0.109:8080/tvshows"
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                textView.text = "Response is: ${response}"
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { response -> textView.text = "${response.message}" })
        queue.add(stringRequest)
        layout?.addView(textView)
    }
}
```

Here's the second:

```
package com.example.tvseriesprojectapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
import android.util.Log
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import android.widget.TextView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.root)

        var listOfShows: MutableList<TvShow> = mutableListOf();
        val url = "http://192.168.0.109:8080/tvshows"
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val textView = TextView(this)
        textView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val gson = Gson();
        var err: String = "";
        var resp: String = "";
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response -> 
                textView.text = response },
            Response.ErrorListener { response -> textView.text = "${response.message}" }
            )
        queue.add(stringRequest)
//        mock
        val str: String = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Everybody hates Chris\",\"category\":\"comedy\",\"year\":2005},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Friends\",\"category\":\"comedy\",\"year\":1994}]";
        listOfShows = gson.fromJson(str, Array<TvShow>::class.java).toMutableList()

        for (one in listOfShows) {
            val textView = TextView(this)
            textView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
            textView.text = "Name: ${one.name} \n Category: ${one.category} \n Year: ${one.year}"
            layout?.addView(textView)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried just to print response, log it, try to make it to var resp and then show it, checked it on debug, nothing worked, what I get just "".

Comment: please add your error message.

Comment: There's no Error, that's the point! I mean, error starts when I try to parse empty string, but before that - nothing

Comment: I think this problem happen because you tried to add text view dynamically.Do you ever tested another ways to show result?

Comment: Yes, as I said, I tried to var it to resp, to print it, to debug it and e.t.c. The reason why I stopped at textView because it worked first time, but not now